# AttributeError at /profile/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The problem comes when i click on profile button to see the profile of the user

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after changing your models?

Comment: Can you post the actual traceback and the full model?

Comment: AttributeError at /profile/
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this and Sign-Up Again :-

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @receiver(post_save,sender=User)
    def post_save_create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**What i have changed :-**

I have added *post_save_create_profile* function to add `Profile` with ( while ) registering  User. It will save User and also save a `Profile` for User.

> **Note :** *Don't forget Imports (receiver, post_save) and Also Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` right after changes in `models.py`*